# If and else function didn't work on javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to here. So I was just making a simple code just for fun, but then I was confused why the if and else function can't work. Can anybody help me?

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name","Your name");

if(name != null) {
   alert("Hello, " + name + "!");
}
// Google and Youtube redirect
if (name.onclick == true); {
    confirm("If you like to go to google, Click OK. If you like to go to youtube, Click CANCEL")
};
    if ( confirm == true ); {
        window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/")
    } else {
window.location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/")
    };
```

Comment: Remove the `;` from the `if` line.

Comment: `name` is a string you just got from the `prompt`, so it can't possibly have an `onclick` property.

Comment: `if ( confirm == true )` you never define a variable called `confirm`, and indeed you are calling the global `window.confirm` method. Comparing it to `true` makes no sense, but in this case it will always be "true" because it exists.

Comment: Hey, thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign whatever `confirm` returns to a variable, and check that.

```js
let answer = confirm("If you like Apples, click OK. If you like Bananas more, Click CANCEL");

if (answer === true) {
  console.log('you like apples');
} else {
  console.log('you like bananas');
}
```